# React Native Android remove basic horizontal margin

Tags: android, react-native

I want to remove basic margin on Android.

For example:

Preview image on iOS:

[image: 1]

Here is what it get on Android:
[image: screenshot_1494432478]

At ios preview there is still "small piece" of next slider shown. but on android there is no "small piece".

I've tried set my card to base on device width, but it will ruin the `card` component because there is no horizontal margin at all. And I've tried set all the margin and padding horizontal to `0` still no luck.

```
<Card
    key={i}
    fontFamily={'Circular'}
    image={card.image}
    imageStyle={{height: 150, overflow: 'hidden'}}
    containerStyle={{
        marginBottom: 10, paddingVertical: 0, paddingHorizontal: 0, marginHorizontal: 0, width: Dimensions.get('width').width(),
        borderRadius: 10
    }}
>
```

How can I get the result same like iOS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue  using **containerStyle** prop

> Card

```
<Card
     containerStyle={styles.CardStyle} >

/>
```

> styles.js

```
const styles=StyleSheet.create({
   CardStyle: {
        marginLeft: 0,
        marginRight: 0
}
})
```

[containerStyle prop link for Card in react-native-elements](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/card.html#containerstyle)